# Loop Slide and Cut not working as intended. Any suggestions?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am working through Andrew Price's (Blender Guru) tutorials on YouTube. I am following his tutorial titled "How to Make Towels - Blender Tutorial". In the beginning of this tutorial, he instructs watchers to create a plane and then use Loop Slide and Cut on that plane by clicking CTRL + R and then simply left clicking with the mouse twice to complete the action. He wants watchers to do this because part of the tutorial requires us to subdivide the plane into 50 cuts, but we have scaled the plane along the x-axis and so when we subdivide, those subdivisions are rectangular and we want them to be square. When I use Loop Slide and Cut and then subdivide, I get the following result:

[image]

If you can see it, there are little dots along the center of the plane. The result should look something like the following (but instead of rectangular faces, there should be square faces):

[image]

Has anyone seen this problem before? Can you help me get back on track? Thanks for any help you can offer. :)

EDIT: link to part of tutorial when asked to do Loop Slide and Cut: https://youtu.be/PEpsN1-W-Qw?t=89

Comment: @RayMairlot Thanks. Just edited the post. See the edit for the link to that part of the video.

Comment: After the loopcut he deselect everything, then selects everything by pressing A twice. Then the subdivision operation will affect all of your geometry not just the two vertices you selected.

Comment: @Leander that worked. Thanks for the explanation!